# Regex on a string

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to formulate a regular expression to use on text. Using in-memory variables is not giving the same result.

The below regular expression provides `$1` and `$2` that return what I expect. `rw` results vary. These positions can vary: I am looking to extract the data irrespective of the position in the string.

```
\/vol\/(\w+)\?(\w+|\s+).*rw=(.*\w+)
```

My data:

```
_DATA_
/vol/vol1   -sec=sys,rw=h1:h2,anon=0
/vol/vol1/q1 -sec=sys,rw=h3:h4,anon=0,ro=h1:h2
/vol/vol2/q1  -sec=sys,root=host5,ro=h3:h5,rw=h1:h2,anon=0
```

I'm trying to capture the second and third groups (if it is a space it should return a space), and a list of entries in `rw`, `ro` and `root`.

Comment: There's no `?` in any of your strings, so `\?` won't match.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `(.*\w+)` will match up to the last word character in the line.  What you are looking for is most likely this `([0-9a-z:]+)`

Comment: This works to get the values..now trying the split approach as these values could be in different positions. Thxs

Answer (score 1):

Guessing from your comment in reply to ikegami, maybe the following will give results you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @keys = qw/ rw ro root /;
my $wanted = join "|", @keys;

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($path, $param) = split;
    my ($vol, $q) = (split '/', $path)[2,3];

    my %tmp = map {split /=/} grep /^(?:$wanted)/, split /,/, $param;

    $data{$vol}{$q // ' '} = \%tmp;
}

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%data;

__DATA__
/vol/vol1   -sec=sys,rw=h1:h2,anon=0
/vol/vol1/q1 -sec=sys,rw=h3:h4,anon=0,ro=h1:h2
/vol/vol2/q1  -sec=sys,root=host5,ro=h3:h5,rw=h1:h2,anon=0
```

The output from Data::Dumper is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'vol2' => {
                      'q1' => {
                                'ro' => 'h3:h5',
                                'root' => 'host5',
                                'rw' => 'h1:h2'
                              }
                    },
          'vol1' => {
                      ' ' => {
                               'rw' => 'h1:h2'
                             },
                      'q1' => {
                                'ro' => 'h1:h2',
                                'rw' => 'h3:h4'
                              }
                    }
        };
```

**Update:** *can you tell me what does (?:) mean in the grep?*

`(?: . . .)` is a non-capturing group. It is used in this case because the beginning of the regex has `^`. Without grouping, the regex would attempt to match `ro` positioned at the beginning of the string or `rw` or `root` anywhere in the string (not just the beginning).

`/^ro|rw|root/` rather than `/^(?:ro|rw|root)/`

The second expression helps the search along because it knows to only attempt a match at the beginning of the string for all 3 patterns and not to try to match anywhere in the string (speeds things up although in your case, there are only 3 alternating matches to attempt - so, wouldn't make a huge difference here). But, still a good practice to follow.

*what does (// ' ') stand for?*

That is the *defined or operator*. The expression `$q // ' '` says to use `$q` for the key in the hash if it is defined **or** a space instead.

You said in your original post *I'm trying to capture the second and third groups (if it is a space it should return a space)*.

`$q` can be undefined when the split, `my ($vol, $q) = (split '/', $path)[2,3];` has only a `vol` and not a `q` such as in this data line (`/vol/vol1   -sec=sys,rw=h1:h2,anon=0`).

Comment: Thank you Chris..this what am looking for.

Comment: Hi Chris,  getting an error on the search expression..can you tell me what does (?:) mean in the grep? Also, you have dumped the data into another hash with the required vol and q names. what does (// ' ') stand for..

Comment: @jsks See my update that answers your questions. _getting an error on the search expression_  That shouldn't be. Did you copy and paste the code - it runs fine here.

Comment: For the second question in that case, wouldn;t it be || ' ' instead of two forward slahes(//)?

Comment: when used print Dumper \%data inside the while loop it is with the format looking for. Inside While loop with print Dumper \%data;
$VAR1 = { 'vol2' => { 'q1' => { 'ro' => 'h3:h5', 'root' => 'host5',                            'rw' => 'h1:h2'
                                              }
                                    }
        };

Outside While loop with print Dumper \%data;

$VAR1 = {  'vol1' => {  'q2' => { 'rw' => 'h1:h2'                                           },
                                      'q1' => $VAR1->{'vol1'}{'q2'}
                                    }
        };

Comment: @jsks Don't know why you're getting those results - I think you're using a different data set - `vol1` in the supplied data set didn't have a `q2`. You might want to post a new question with the code that produced that with the data in question.  _For the second question in that case, wouldn;t it be || ' ' instead of two forward slahes(//)?_ In this situation, that will also work but it is more correct to say `//` as that checks for `definedness`. The `||` checks for `true` or `false`. False values are `undef`, 0, '0', 0.0 or '', (the empty string). Truth is anything else.

Comment: Here is the script and it gives an error when using // '' as search pattern not terminated. Though, played a little on the input data, here is output with original data..$VAR1 = {
          'vol2' => {
                      'q1' => {
                                'ro' => 'h3:h5',
                                'root' => 'host5',
                                'rw' => 'h1:h2'
                              }
                    },
          'vol1' => {
                      '' => $VAR1->{'vol2'}{'q1'},
                      'q1' => $VAR1->{'vol2'}{'q1'}
                    }
        };

Comment: Disregard on the result..realized my mistake..have define %tmp as global array and made it local in the while loop and problem fixed.  Only issue it has is (|| '')vs // ''. // - gives an error this is not properly terminated.

Comment: @jsks The [defined or operator //](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#Defined-or-operator) was added to perl version 5.010 so I suspect your version of perl is earlier. Version 5.08, 5.06, . . .

Comment: Thank you Chris..thats what it is..it is a old version i had.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you want, but a regex would not make a good parser here.

```
while (<DATA>) {
   my ($path, $opts) = split;
   my %opts =
      map { my ($k,$v) = split(/=/, $_, 2); $k=>$v }
         split(/,/, $opts);

   ...
}
```

(`my %opts = split(/[,=]/, $opts);` might suffice.)

Comment: This is the end result am looking for vol1{q1}{rw => hosts, ro => hosts, root=>hosts}   Checking the suggested..

Comment: What am i doing wrong here?                                                               while(<$fh>){
  
   my($path, $opts)= split;
   $path=/\/vol\/(\w+)\/?(\w+|\s+)/;
   print "$1:$2 \n";
   #print $path;
   %opts=map{chomp;s/-sec=sys//g;s/anon=0//g;my($k,$v)=split(/=/,$opts,2);$opts{$1}{$2}{$k}=$v;}
   print Dumper \%opts;
  
 }
close $fh;

Comment: I don't know what that means